# Non-fatal XAML exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I do something illegal in XAML, e.g. binding to a non-existing source all exceptions are silently handled and logged to the output console. I like to have these in a log file, in case this happens when this occurs when my application runs at the customer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52) talks about how to set up the trace sources for WPF so that a filtered set of the bindings messages can be output to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `DispatchUnhandledExceptionEventHandler` for the entire application to catch errors in your application

There is a tutorial here: [Exception handling made easy in XAML Applications](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/5d2dda03-0791-4eca-8a2c-a4d2a2d0244b/exception-handling-made-e.aspx)